# java.lang.LinkageError on Websphere while trying to load HttpUriRequest

Tags: java, maven, websphere, linkageerror

I'm using CUPS4J for my project, which depends on http-client, http-core, and slf4j.

To resolve dependencies we use Maven, and I have defined dependencies as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cups4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>cups4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

The cups4j dependency is on our ArtiFactory server (I couldn't find it online).

Everything works like a charm if I create a sample `main` method to print some document and launch it as a java application.

When I publish my classes to the Websphere server and call that method from a webpage, it generates a `java.lang.LinkageError`.

This is the relevant part of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader "org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader@208c132" previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest" defined by loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@1e0f797"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:584)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:708)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:700)
    at org.cups4j.operations.IppOperation.sendRequest(IppOperation.java:207)
    at org.cups4j.operations.IppOperation.request(IppOperation.java:76)
    at org.cups4j.CupsPrinter.print(CupsPrinter.java:113)
    at it.dropcomp.tasks.print.PrinterService.printPDF(PrinterService.java:160)
```

This is the method that prints the PDF (Inside `it.dropcomp.tasks.print.PrinterService`):

```
public void printPDF() throws RemoteServiceException {
    /* 
     * generatedPDF is defined as File, and it's properly initialized 
     * before calling this method.
     */
    if(generatedPDF == null) {
        throw new RemoteServiceException("You must generate a file first!");
    }
    try {
        CupsPrinter selectedPrinter = new CupsPrinter(
            new URL(Constants.PRINTER_FULL_URL), 
            Constants.PRINTER_NAME, true
        );
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(generatedPDF);
        PrintJob pj = new PrintJob.Builder(is).build();
        selectedPrinter.print(pj); //this is line 160
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception", e);
        throw new RemoteServiceException(e);
    }
}
```

It seems that `HttpUriRequest` already exists and makes conflict with the one provided by the `httpclient` library from Apache, but if I try removing that dependency from `pom.xml`, I get a `NoClassDefFoundException` for that class.

If it matters, my IDE is Eclipse Luna.

How can I solve this exception?

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere uses also httpclient library which may conflict with one you are providing.
Try to create isolated shared library in admin console via `Environment > Shared Libraries`. Put `http-*`, `slf4j` and `cups4j` jars there and associate that shared library with your application.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. I must use Maven to resolve dependencies, I work in a team and the team leader wants it to be done this way. I read that I can tell maven that the library is provided, so that it doesn't include the jar when the application gets deployed on the server. I'll try with this approach, maybe it solves the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @BackSlash You can still `build` with maven, there is no problem with that, but as you wrote, you need to mark these dependencies as provided and not include in the application, but unfortunately configure it on the application server as library. You may try to change just the classloader in the application settings to Parent Last, but it rather not gonna solve your issue.